# Contract function call in different way

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

To access any function of contract, we use : 
`contractInstance.functionname.sendtransaction() or contractInstance.functionname.call()`


Is it possible to call it as : 
`contractInstance[functionname].sendtransaction() or contractInstance["functionname"].call()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `contractInstance["functionname"].call()` and `contractInstance["functionname"].sendTransaction()` work.

Comment: Have you implemented it?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on a small project of mine.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) you will find all the methods used to call a function from web3.js

```
// Automatically determines the use of call or sendTransaction based on the method type
myContractInstance.myMethod(param1 [, param2, ...] [, transactionObject] [, defaultBlock] [, callback]);

// Explicitly calling this method
myContractInstance.myMethod.call(param1 [, param2, ...] [, transactionObject] [, defaultBlock] [, callback]);

// Explicitly sending a transaction to this method
myContractInstance.myMethod.sendTransaction(param1 [, param2, ...] [, transactionObject] [, callback]);

// Get the call data, so you can call the contract through some other means
var myCallData = myContractInstance.myMethod.getData(param1 [, param2, ...]);
// myCallData = '0x45ff3ff6000000000004545345345345..'
```